# Were there prehistoric interaction between Caucasian and Asian people?

Tags: europe, asia, archaeology

Are there any documented instances of prehistoric interaction between Caucasian and Asian people?  Do archeological sites such as [Xiaohe Tomb complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaohe_Tomb_complex) imply there were?

Comment: I'd be very impressed with anyone who could make a moderately reasonable argument that there *wasn't*. Technically speaking, the caucasuses are even **in** Asia. What makes you think there might not have been?

Comment: Maybe i should limit the scope to Eastern Asian.  Before the Silk Road, are there interactions between eastern asian and European people? The geological closeness between the home ranges of Mongoloid and Caucasoid probably mean they must have lots of opportunities to interact.  Are there many evidences?

Comment: While you are editing your question, I'd suggest changing the terms too. As per wikipedia, "the term mongoloid is now considered derogatory by the scientific community due to its association with discredited typological models of racial classification." . "Caucasoid" and "Caucasian" are even worse, as that term now refers to a specific people  living between the Black and Caspian seas. They aren't even Indo-Europeans.

Comment: What do you mean by Asians?